# Deriving admittance matrix for shortened quarter-wavelength transmission line

Tags: rf, transmission-line

For [Reduced-size branch-line and rat-race hybrids for uniplanar MMIC's](http://sci-hub.tw/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/45344) , how to derive equation (2) ?

and is the imaginary constant *j* needed in equation (1) ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: For equation (1) , I am trying to use [MATLAB y2abcd() function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rf/ug/y2abcd.html) to convert admittance matrix to ABCD matrix.

However, I am getting mismatch between [MATLAB answer](https://i.imgur.com/tpXeKWN.png) and [actual theoretical result](https://i.imgur.com/6FXNyjF.png)